# If methods are neither virtual nor sealed by default, then why does this method override of a non-virtual and non-sealed method work?

Tags: c#, inheritance, methods

On several occasions, I've been told that methods in C# classes are neither sealed nor virtual by default. Despite this, the follow code works just fine and prints the two clearly intended strings. This is strong evidence that I've very confused. What default or feature am I ignorant of?

```cs
Child ExampleChild = new Child();
ExampleChild.SayHello();
Parent ExampleParent = new Parent();
ExampleParent.SayHello();

public class Parent
{
    public void SayHello() => Console.WriteLine("Hello from parent");
}
public class Child : Parent
{
    public void SayHello() => Console.WriteLine("Hello from child");
}
```

Comment: You are not _overriding_, you are **hiding** the base method. Two entirely different things which should never be confused with each other, because they are different things that _can_ exhibit different behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're defining a new method (`Child.SayHello()`), which hides the parent method. There's a compiler warning telling you so.

The new method should ideally be marked with `new` to make the intention clear. It won't partake in dynamic dispatch, i.e. if you have a variable of type `Parent`, then `Parent.SayHello()` will be called.

See also [C# Inheritance and Member Hiding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21999059/c-sharp-inheritance-and-member-hiding).

Comment: So what does that make the default keyword for methods? It's as if there's some `hideable` keyword that I've never heard of.

Comment: You could look at it like that, yes. Overriding is only allowed on abstract or virtual members, but hiding is allowed on all instance members, IIRC.

Comment: If you run `Parent p = new Child();` and then `p.SayHello();`, you will get a different response depending on whether `SayHello` is `virtual` or not. If it's not virtual (the default) the static type of `p` (the type of the variable `p`, i.e.  `Parent`) will determine which is run (i.e., it will run the `Parent` version). If it's virtual, the dynamic type of `p` (the type of the object `p` refers to, `Child`) makes the determination